# È "memorioso" una parola ormai comunemente accettata?

Tags: word-usage

Sento che alcune persone, che hanno ottime capacità di memorizzazione, dicono 'ho un cervello memorioso'.

"Memorioso" sembra avere una sonorità interessante, tanto che forse può essere considerata una parola *doc* così come le altre.

Cosa sapreste dirmi in merito? Usate o conoscete questa parola?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a polling.

Comment: I've never heard it. But word jokes adding *-oso* are common; *è risparmiosa* was used for advertising a car. I don't think this is a good question.

Comment: Per quel che conta, è la prima volta che lo sento.

Comment: Mai sentito in effetti...

Comment: Non c'è nel dizionario, magari era "cervello prodigioso"..

Comment: "Memorioso" è spagnolo - ed è per questo che ha questa bella sonorità :-)

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of. I don't even think it's in a dictionary. It could be a funny way to say "memorabile" as if you talk to a little kid or as a joke, but it's not used on formal/normal occasions.

Comment: Well, but the OP refers to a meaning which is different from the one of "memorabile". So it should be a different case from, for example, "morbido" becoming "morbidoso".

Comment: I know, on the OP example, "ho un cervello memorioso", it means that he has a great brain because it can remember things. But "memorioso" it's not really a word or at least it's far less used then "morbidoso" which I hear almost every day.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all used nowadays. If you want to praise someone for his/her memory, you could just say

> Ha buona memoria

Comment: Was it used in the past?